# How to create file object of pdf from blob url (URL.createObjectURL())

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, pdf

I have created Object url of PDF file using url: URL.createObjectURL(file[0]).

e.g url = blob:http://0.0.0.0:5002/e468fb70-d597-4b17-bb3a-ec6272f2d7fe.

**Now what I want to do is,**
read pdf from url=blob:http://0.0.0.0:5002/e468fb70-d597-4b17-bb3a-ec6272f2d7fe and create file object like

```
File(61) 
{
   name: "ICT_zbbihfc_dummy.pdf", 
   lastModified: 1548148972779, 
   lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 22 2019 17:22:52 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), 
   webkitRelativePath: "", 
   size: 61,
   type: "application/pdf",
   webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

This is in Javascript.

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to create a `File` object from a `Blob`? (Separately: I very much doubt it's possible, but you probably don't need to anyway...)

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder for replying. I am selecting files from input tag. after then I am creating blob url of it. and now on submit button I want to read file from blob url as File Object..then send File Object to server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert **Blob object url of PDF or Image to File object**

```
var file_object = fetch('blob:http://0.0.0.0:5002/e468fb70-d597-4b17-bb3a-ec6272f2d7fe') 
          .then(r => r.blob())
          .then(blob => {
              var file_name = Math.random().toString(36).substring(6) + '_name.pdf'; //e.g ueq6ge1j_name.pdf
              var file_object = new File([blob], file_name, {type: 'application/pdf'});
              console.log(file_object); //Output
           });
//-------
```

To convert **Base64 of Image to File object**

```
var file_object = fetch('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA') 
          .then(r => r.blob())
          .then(blob => {
              var file_name = Math.random().toString(36).substring(6) + '_name.jpeg'; //e.g ueq6ge1j_name.jpeg
              var file_object = new File([blob], file_name, {type: 'application/jpeg'});
              console.log(file_object); //Output
           });
//-------
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you clarified:

> I am selecting files from input tag. after then I am creating blob url of it. and now on submit button I want to read file from blob url as File Object..then send File Object to server.

You don't need a `File` object to do that. You can simply send the `Blob`, for instance using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)'s [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method, which accepts `Blob`s.

However: If you have the `input`, and you've got the `File` from the `input`'s `files` array, you may as well just use it directly rather than reading it and creating a `Blob`.

It's probably worth pointing out that `input type="file"` elements have a [`multiple` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-input-multiple) that can be used to specify that it can be used for multiple files (which is why the `files` property is a collection).

Comment: I am using one input field for multiple time to select files. For example, In first time, I choose image file and pdf file. then display that image and pdf file in web page using blob url (i am saving this blob url in array).. In second time I choose another file. so again new blob url push to array. then on submit all file send to server

Comment: @NaisargParmar - That's fine, just keep the `File` objects.

Comment: Actually I am new to it. and also in case, if file name is same then it may create problem.

Comment: @NaisargParmar - Only if the server blindly uses the name without checking for conflicts. It's not a problem in terms of sending multiple files in the same request with the same anme.

Comment: I will try solution to keep File Objects. Thank you @T.J. Crowder